# Checking that all records from a table has been included into the main table

Tags: sql, netezza

I new to SQL but I have been practicing JOIN a bit. I want to check if all the records from another table(`small_table`) has been included in my current table(`base_table`).

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM base_table WHERE year = 2015 AND month = 3 AND day = 4
```

will return to me a set of records based on todays date. `small_table` is the same structure. I want to return the count of a `INNER JOIN` (compared on all columns) and see if it equals the number of records in `small_table`. This will prove that every row/record from `small_table` is included in `base_table` based on todays date.

I don't need to use `JOIN` but it is simply the first method I thought of. I am open to other methods. I am having trouble creating this query.

```
A = SELECT * FROM small_table;
B = SELECT * FROM base_table WHERE year = 2015 AND month = 3 AND day = 4;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A INNER JOIN B;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways I think you can do this.
Assuming you don't want to see all the records individually, I think COUNT is the way to go.
If you want to use a JOIN, you need to join the two tables on some kind of identifier.

```
SELECT COUNT(s.*)
FROM small_table s
INNER JOIN base_table b
ON s.ID = b.ID
WHERE b.year = 2015 AND b.month = 3 AND b.day = 4;
```

The ID above is whatever your primary key would be.

Alternatively, you can use a UNION statement, which I think is the better approach.

```
SELECT 'Small Table' as Table_Name, COUNT(*)
FROM small_table
UNION
SELECT 'Base Table', COUNT(*)
FROM base_table
WHERE year = 2015 AND month = 3 AND day = 4;
```

I expect this would show something like this:

> Table_Name | COUNT(*)
>
> Small Table | 200
>
> Base Table | 200

Where 200 is the count of each table.

Hope this helps!